# How to compare a number from different lines of input?

Tags: java, string, integer

I had a question I was trying to do where according to a metric, we have to determine the best line, which is the no. of spaces divided by no. of characters in the line. The line with best such ratio gets printed out. I can do that, but if a line with a lower such ratio comes out, it is not to be printed. but how do we compare the ratios?? See here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BestLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a line of text: ");
    double temp = 0.0;
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
         String sentence = s.nextLine();
         String chars = sentence.trim();
         int whtspacs = sentence.length() - chars.length();
         int totchars = chars.length();
         double ratio = (double) whtspacs/totchars;

         if (ratio < temp) {
          break;
          }

          temp = ratio;

          System.out.println("Best line so far is: " + sentence);
        }

      System.out.println("Best Line was: " );    

      }

}
```

Thanks for telling me about using another variable, but now here's the code again and it's not working? Sorry for asking a simple question, but I just don't get it! Again, thanks so much

Comment: if (ratio < ratio) ??. Don't you think that you need to keep another variable holding the biggest ratio value?

Comment: It is not working? ... Can you Show the output Along with input also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this :

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> ratios=new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<String> sentences=new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("Enter a line of text: ");
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String sentence = s.nextLine();
            // Get the number of white spaces
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
                if(Character.isWhitespace(sentence.charAt(i))) count++;
            }
            //number of Characters
            int totchars = sentence.length()-count;
            //Add the ratio to our ArrayList
            ratios.add((double) count / totchars);
            // Add the Sentence to ArrayList
            sentences.add(sentence);
            if (sentence.length()==0) {
                break;
            }

        }
        //Find The best Ratio
        int best=0;
        for(int i=0;i<ratios.size();i++) {
            if(ratios.get(i)<ratios.get((int)best))
                best=i;
        }
        System.out.println("Best line so far is: " + sentences.get((int)best));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Declare outside loop
double temp=0.0;//Or set to Max
//Inside loop
double ratio = (double) whtspacs/totchars;
      if (ratio < temp) {//At first will use default value of temp 0.0
      //OR Maybe You want if(temp < ratio)
          break;
      }
//.....Your code
temp=ratio;//after comparison with old value set current value to temp
```

*One more thing I want to suggest you that you should store all double values to `Arraylist` and after that sort `Arraylist` and you will get smallest value to find best line so far right now in your code it will break as last line has more spcaces than current one (and won't allow to add more lines) or vice verca (as you code).*

Comment: Thanks, but can you check the code again? I added what you said, still doesn't work, I feel like I'm close but not yet there

Comment: _You need to add preceding or trailing spaces in input to check._

Comment: Don't forget to have another variable, to store the best line found so far.